Are Om and Pranava the same?
Is there any authoritative verse in any scripture that says Om and Pranava are the same?
I have searched extensively but have found nothing that says Om is the pranava.
There are verses that contain "pranava" and verses containing "om" but none equating the two.
Is this only an inference?

The meaning of Pranava is explained by Subrahmanya in the Shiva Purana Kailāsa-Saṃhitā Chapter 14 - The Praṇava in the form of Śiva:

सुब्रह्मण्य उवाच ।
श्रूयताम्मुनिशार्दूल त्वया यत्पृष्टमादरात् ।
समष्टिव्यष्टिभावेन परिज्ञानम्महेशितुः ॥ ८ ॥

प्रणवार्त्थपरिज्ञानरूपं तद्विस्तरादहम् ।
वदामि षड्विधार्थैक्य परिज्ञानेन सुव्रत ॥ ९ ॥

O revered sage, you have enquired about the perfect knowledge of Śiva
in his composite and individual state. O performer of good rites, I
shall explain that in detail Perfect knowledge comprises the meaning
of Praṇava by realising the unity of six topics.

One of these 6 topics is the Mantra form of the Pranava:

तत्र मन्त्रस्वरूपन्ते वदामि मुनिसत्तम ।
येन विज्ञातमात्रेण महाज्ञानी भवेन्नरः ॥ १२ ॥

O excellent sage, I shall explain to you the form of the mantra which
makes a man possessed of perfect knowledge.


आद्यस्स्वरः पंचमश्च पञ्चमान्तस्ततः परः ।
बिन्दुनादौ च पञ्चार्णाः प्रोक्ता वेदैर्न चान्यथा ॥ १३ ॥

The first and the fifth vowels, the fifth letter of the fifth class of
consonants, Bindu and Nāda these five letters are mentioned by the
Vedas.
The initial mantra of the Vedas i.e. Oṃ is of the composite form. Nāda
too is the composite of all. The set of four with Bindu as the fifth
is established as Vyaṣṭi in the Praṇava that expresses Śiva.

As per the above verses, if we look at the Sanskrit Vowels i.e., the first and fifth vowels, they are Aa and U (highlighted below):

The fifth letter of the fifth class of consonants is Ma:

As per rules of grammar when these are combined together along with the Bindu (dot) and the nada (sound), Om is produced which is the Pranava Mantra.


Tasya VAcakah pranavah
His (Ishvara) designator is "AUM" ~Yoga Sutras 27

But this doesn't mean Pranava = AUM, so how?
Patanjali did not give a thesis, he gave equations. Hence, they were called sutras. It's up to a Guru or a Student to explore and decode each Sutra.
So what is PRANAVA?
The Sutra itself says that Pranava is the Vachaka of Ishwara.
What is Vachaka?
In Mantra Yoga it has a specialized meaning and is used for a name which is essentially of the nature of a Mantra.
What is Mantra?
An aspect related to Shabdha-Brahma with the power, when used in a prescribed manner of revealing the CONSCIOUSNESS (self).
A Vacaka is a name which has a mystic relationship with the Vacya (the Entity designated in the mantra of the Vedas) and has inherent in it the power of revealing the consciousness and releasing the power of the individual for whom it stands. Such a Vacaka is AUM. It is considered to be the most mystical, sacred, and powerful Mantra because it is the Vacaka or Ishvara (that which is sovereign) the greatest power and supreme consciousness.
~The Science of Yoga, by IK Taimni Sutra 25-29******
Who and what is Ishwara?
Isha = Ruler, Ownership
Swara = sovereign
What is the which is Self Ruling? This body is not self-governed, because it's ruled by Prakruti, and the senses it created. The Jiva? No, because the Jiva carries all the Vasanas from one life to the other. The true SELF, the Atman (jiva's Atman = Jivatma) is what that is Sovereign. Brahman is what is Sovereign.
So what is the Vachaka "the word"? And how can one confirm that this Word is AUM which is SELF, which is SOVEREIGN, which has the power to bring out the SELF. Why is Patanjali associating his sutra (equation) with the Word of Ishwara?
For this let's move to Mandukya Upanishad (one of the primary Upanishads)

सोऽयमात्माध्यक्षरमोङ्कारोऽधिमात्रं पादा मात्रा मात्राश्च पादा अकार
उकारो मकार इति ॥ ८॥
so'yam ātmādhyakṣaram auṁkaro'dhimātram pādā mātrā mātrāś ca pādā
akāra ukāra makāra iti. 8

This identical Ātman, or Self, in the realm of sound is the syllable OM, the above described four quarters of the Self being identical with the components of the syllable, and the components of the syllable being identical with the four quarters of the Self. The components of the Syllable are A, U, M.

ॐ इत्येतदक्षरमिदꣳ सर्वं तस्योपव्याख्यानं भूतं भवद् भविष्यदिति
सर्वमोङ्कार एव यच्चान्यत् त्रिकालातीतं तदप्योङ्कार एव ॥ १॥
aum ity etad akṣaram idam sarvam, tasyopavyākhyānam  bhūtam bhavad
bhaviṣyad iti sarvam auṁkāra eva yac cānyat trikālātītaṁ tad apy
auṁkāra eva. 1

OM! – This Imperishable Word is the whole of this visible universe. Its explanation is as follows: What has become, what is becoming, what will become, – verily, all of this is OM. And what is beyond these three states of the world of time, – that too, verily, is OM. (1)
If AUM is not the Vachaka of Ishwara? And that Vachaka is not Pranava, then what is the Vachaka of Ishwara? Is there another Pranava apart from AUM that is used by Ishwara?

My question was triggered by this sutra :-)
The source then is anumana and agama?

Uttering Om by speech, has both - qualification and restrictions. It's part of mantra.
So as common practice, in restricted conditions, Pranav is used to indicate Om.
